# Rails - active model serialize an array of hashes within a serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I am trying to create a nested serialized array of hashes. I have the following so far. It doesn't return the nested serializer but just the array of hashes.

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ReportShowSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :name, :schedule, :uuid, :reports

       has_many :reports, each_serializer: ReportBuildSerializer

      def reports
        [
          {date: '2018-10-04', test: 'a'},
          {date: '2018-10-03', test: 'b'}
        ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and the other serializer

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ReportBuildSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :test, :date, :var


      def var
        "var"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

but it returns the following

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "reports",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Another test report",
            "schedule": "weekly",
            "uuid": "f10736ae-bf5c-4e43-8cd4-35eb0dc12efd",
            "reports": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-04",
                    "test": "ff"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-10-03",
                    "test": "ff"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

So I don't think it is using the `ReportBuildSerializer`

Comment: You should rename/remove the `reports` method I guess, it conflicts with the associated serializer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you render your objects(`reports`) probably in the `controller`. Could you make sure that you do it like this:

```
render json: @reports, include: 'reports'
```

---

If it does not work then you can go with another approach:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class ReportShowSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :name, :schedule, :uuid, :reports

       has_many :reports, each_serializer: ReportBuildSerializer

      def reports
        [
          ::Api::V1:: ReportBuildSerializer.new({date: '2018-10-04', test: 'a'}).attributes,
          ::Api::V1:: ReportBuildSerializer.new({date: '2018-10-03', test: 'b'}).attributes
        ]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would rename it to something like `build_report`

So I would update the code like this?


`
module Api
  module V1
    class ReportShowSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
      attributes :name, :schedule, :uuid, :build_report

       has_many :build_report, each_serializer: ReportBuildSerializer

      def build_report
        [
          {date: '2018-10-04', test: 'ff'},
          {date: '2018-10-03', test: 'ff'}
        ]
      end
    end
  end
end
`

Comment: Don't rename it before you try to use `include`. I think your code should work as it is. It's just not using the `include`/`has_many` feature.

Comment: Could you share how you use this serializer? how do you render your reports?

Comment: Should I change `render json: @reports, include: 'reports'` to `render json: @reports, include: 'build_report'`

Comment: Don't use `build_report`. Your code was better and rollback your code to `reports` as in your initial question. Then use `render json: @reports, include: 'reports'`.

Comment: so like this
`render json: report, status: 200,  serializer: ReportShowSerializer, include: 'reports'`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181272/discussion-between-tarek-n-elsamni-and-max-rose-collins).